# Why does the amount of dask task increase with an "optimized" chunking compared to a "basic" chunking schema?

Tags: dask, python-xarray

I'm trying to understand how different chunking schemas can speed up or slow down my computation using xarray and dask.
I have read [dask](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/array-chunks.html) and [xarray](https://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/user-guide/dask.html#chunking-and-performance) guides but I might have missed something to understand this.

### Problem

I have 2 storage with the same content but chunked differently.
Both contains a data variable *tasmax* and the necessary coordinate variables and metadata for it to be opened with xarray.
tasmax shape is `<xarray.DataArray 'tasmax' (time: 3660, lat: 256, lon: 512)>`

The first storage is a zarr store `zarr_init` which I made from netCDF files, 1 file per year, 10 .nc files.
When opening it with xarray I get a chunking schema of `chunksize=(366, 256, 512)`, thus 1 year per chunk, same as the initial netCDF storage.
Each chunk is around 191MB.

The second storage, `zarr_time_opti` is also a zarr store but, there is no chunking on time dimension.
When I open it with xarray and inspect `tasmax`, it's chunking schema is `chunksize=(3660, 114, 115)`.
Each chunk is around 191MB as well.

**Naively, I would expect spatially independent computations to run much faster and to generate much fewer tasks on `zarr_time_opti` than on `zarr_init`.
However, I observe the complete opposite:**

When computing the same calculus based on `groupby("time.month")`, I get 2370 tasks with `zarr_time_opti` and only 570 tasks with `zarr_init`. As you can see with the MRE below, this has nothing to do with zarr itself as I'm able to reproduce the issue with only xarray and dask.

So my questions are:

- What is the mechanism with xarray or dask which create that many tasks ?
- Then, what would be the strategy to find the best chunking schema ?

### MRE

```
def simple_climate_index(da):
    import time
    time_start = time.perf_counter()
    # computations
    res =( da.groupby("time.month") - da.groupby("time.month").mean("time")).compute()
    # summer_days = (da > 25).resample(time="MS").sum().compute()
    time_elapsed = time.perf_counter() - time_start
    print(f"wall time: {time_elapsed} secs")


def mre_so():
    import distributed
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    client = distributed.Client(memory_limit="16GB", n_workers=1, threads_per_worker=4)
    tasmax = xr.DataArray(
        data=np.empty((3660, 256, 512), dtype=float),
        dims=["time", "lat", "lon"],
        coords=dict(
            time=pd.date_range("2042-01-01", periods=3660, freq="D"),
            lat=np.arange(256),
            lon=np.arange(512),
        ),
        name="tasmax",
        attrs={"units": "degC"},
    )
    da_optimized = tasmax.copy(deep=True).chunk(dict(time=-1, lat=114, lon=115))
    simple_climate_index(da_optimized)
    # wall time: ~47 secs - 2370 tasks (observed on client)
    da_init = tasmax.copy(deep=True).chunk(dict(time=366, lat=-1, lon=-1))
    simple_climate_index(da_init)
    # wall time: ~37 secs - 570 tasks (observed on client)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    mre_so()
```

---

### Notes

- `zarr_time_opti` is obtained by rechunking `zarr_init` with [rechunker](https://rechunker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html), a library  to efficiently rewrite to different chunking schemas.
- In reality, I'm doing time series analyses by computing (for example) the 90th daily percentile over 30 years on each pixel and then computing the exceedance rate of tasmax compare to this percentile on each pixel again.
  And in this case, using ~100 years I get around 2000 tasks when time is chunked and around 85000 when time is **not** chunked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is the mechanism with xarray or dask which create that many tasks ?

In the case of `da_optimized`, you seem to be chunking along both `lat` and `lon` dimensions, and in `da_init`, you're chunking along only the `time` dimension.

`da_optimized`:

[image]

`da_init`:

[image]

When you do a compute, in the beginning, each task will correspond to one chunk.

---

**Sidenotes** about your specific example:

1. `da_optimized` starts with 15 chunks and `da_init` with 10, this is adding to fewer overall tasks in `da_init`. So, to balance them, I've modified it to be:

```py
da_optimized = tasmax.copy(deep=True).chunk(dict(time=-1, lat=128, lon=103))
```

2. While executing, xarray shows this warning: `PerformanceWarning: Slicing with an out-of-order index is generating 11 times more chunks`. So, I've simplifies the comupation in `simple_climate_index` to be:

```py
res = da.groupby("time.month").mean("time").compute()
```

---

The best chunking technique would depend on what operation you're doing.

For a `groupby` operation, commonly seen in pandas, I can see why `da_init` has fewer tasks, and is faster. All the `lat`+`lon` data is conserved within a chunk for any given timestamp. (Moreover, Dask can optimize the number of chunks based on `groups` in this case. For example, you're grouping-by month, so even if you start with 100 chunks, you'll end up with 12 groups, which can potentially be stored as one-group-per-chunk, so, 12 chunks in total. I'm not sure if xarray actually does this optimization, I'm just saying it's possible.)

In `da_optimized`, a `groupby` will require communication between chunks because the `lat`+`lon` data are spread across different chunks, which will result in more tasks, and therefore a performance penalty.

Here are the (task) graph visualizations for both operations:

`da_optimized`:

[image]

`da_init`:

[image]

---

> Then, what would be the strategy to find the best chunking schema ?

Since you're doing the `groupby()` on "time", the task graph would be most efficient if you chunk along the same (time) dimension.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it. You said "on da_optimized, a groupby will require lat+lon data to be moved across chunks". 
But my groupby operation is done on "time" dimension: `da.groupby("time.month")`. I can indeed see that it creates many more tasks but, I still don't understand **why**. What are these movements across chunks that are needed ?

Comment: In other words, if I were to do it without dask: To group values by month I would iterate over every pixel (a lat;lon couple) and load in memory every values of the time-series for the pixel in loop.
This is what I tried to replicate by having no chunk on time dimension. The only difference is that it would handles a batch of pixel instead of pixel per pixel loop.

Comment: A `groupby` is essentially creating groups, so, 12 groups for the 12 months in your case, we'll need all the lat+lon values corresponding to a month in the same group. In `da_optimized` no chunk has all the lat+lon values, so Dask will need to communicate between chunks for this. Does this make sense?

Comment: Re your second comment, I'll actually use a different mental model. Think of going through (iterating over) each time value, and finding all with the same month, say January. So, if we have 10-years of daily-data, we'd have 31*10=310 rows along time dimension put into one group. We do this for all months, and then we take the mean for each group. Now, does it make sense why it's useful to have all lat+lon values corresponding to a time value in the same chunk? When we make groups, we're essentially moving all these values into one group.

Comment: Oh! I get it now! thanks for the detailed and insightful answer @pavithraes